# What's the best way to implement an OpenID server (prererably Ruby)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openid

I want to implement an OpenID server in a Ruby on Rails marketplace app to provide single sign-on functionality, similar to the Google Apps marketplace. Just to be clear, I want to build a **server, not a consumer of OpenID**.

The official Ruby library is on Github - https://github.com/openid/ruby-openid, but there have been no recent commits there. The last one was 2 years ago. It's the same story with Python and PHP.

Is anyone using these libraries? Are there any actively maintained alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but you'd mostly active development in OpenId consumers more than OpenId, 
You can checkout https://github.com/josh/rack-openid, which is a wrapper around ruby-openId.

There are some others like https://github.com/nov/openid_connect , which is in early active development.

Comment: Thanks, openid_connect looks good. I also found this one - https://github.com/dbloete/masquerade